# Cannot Install Appcelerator CLI or SDK

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-sdk

I am trying to install Appcelerator CLI and SDK, but I get errors all the time. I´m using Windows.
When I do `npm install appcelerator -g`, in cmd, (run as admin) I get:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 122 packages, and audited 123 packages in 9s

4 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

And, when I run `appc`, in cmd (run as admin) I get `program.allowUnknownOption is not a function`.

When I install the extension in VSCode, as detailed on VSCode official marketplace and Titanium WebSite, and the click "Install Tooling", this `Titanium SDK Titanium Updates: Installing Titanium SDK: 10.1.1.GA (1/1)` simply doesn´t install.

Please, someone help me install the CLI and the Titanium SDK. (I know I have to use it in VSCode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't mention your nodejs version (sounds like a wrong one, use nodejs 14 to be safe) do the following steps as mentioned on
https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/installation.md#quick-install

I've updated a existing setup but i wasn't using it for a longer time so it is the same as a new install:

- update/install the CLI (admin command prompt): `npm i -g titanium alloy appcelerator`
- enable "dev mode" in Windows in the security settings to run node scripts
- ti sdk install 10.1.1.GA to have the latest SDK
- download OpenJDK from https://jdk.java.net/archive (11.0.2)
- extract the ZIP to e.g. c:\programms\java\jdk-11.0.2
- set system JAVA_HOME variable to the same folder
- restart command prompt

That said: please make sure to start use the `ti` cli instead of `appc`. You can enable the open source version in the VSCode package.

Here is a tutorial which steps you'll need to do when switching the CLI: https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/appc_to_ti.md

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Node Version is 16.13.1

Comment: Thank you! I wish appcelerator had better documentation of how to switch from appc to ti, so this was very helpful

Comment: until 2 days ago there was no need for them to provide that information :) That's why I wrote that tutorial a year ago so you could switch over early. Glad it helped you!